# Button doesn't working when expanding tableview in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, autolayout

I am new to iOS programming I have Implemented `UITableviewController`, The below is the design of my Controller,

```
UITableViewController---          
       UIView-----               (1)
           Label---Label         (2)
           label---Label         (3)
           label---              (4)
           UItableview           (5)
           textfield             (6)
           textfield             (7)
           UIButton.             (8)
           UIButton.             (9)
```

and so on.

Here my problem is when I expanding (5) table view height, the bottom button doesn't work, I don't know how to solve this can anyone help suggest some answer to this issues.Below is my Coding Which I tried ...

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   // [ProgressHUD show:@"Please Wait..."];
    array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"testing",@"testing",@"testing",@"testing",@"testing",@"testing",@"testing",@"testing",@"testing",@"testing",@"testing",@"testing",@"testing",@"testing",@"testing",@"testing",@"testing",@"testing",@"testing",@"testing",nil];
[self adjusttableview];
}
-(void) adjusttableview{
    _mytableview. translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
    CGFloat numberofrows=array.count;
    CGFloat height = numberofrows*10;
    _waterheight.constant = height;   //Constraints of my tableview (5) height

    _mytableview.frame =CGRectMake(_mytableview.frame.origin.x,_mytableview.frame.origin.y, _mytableview.frame.size.width,height);


}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

(5) table view height is expanding perfect, But when It expanding the below buttons are doesn't work.

[image: expanded tableview][image: submit button]

Comment: If you are adding constrains no need to add frame for `UITableView`

Comment: can you add any picture of your UI? where you are getting this issue.

Comment: expanded tableview  and ui and all working perfect the only problem is when tableview height get increased the below button are doesn't work why is it so..

Comment: Just remove _mytableview. translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES; and  _mytableview.frame =CGRectMake(_mytableview.frame.origin.x,_mytableview.frame.origin.y, _mytableview.frame.size.width,height); And make sure your buttons are not going outside of their superview after expanding your tableview.

Comment: I have removed that two lines but still button doesn't work ..

Comment: please add storyboard image to question to resolve it.

Comment: I have added my design, I tried many possible but I can't I need to satisfy expand my tableview as well as button want to work properly ,suggest some new code or what I did wrong in my coding??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above scenario your buttons are below the table view so as soon as the table view increase the buttons go out of the bound of the UIView. so the accessibility area is gone.

For this kind of the setup, where dynamic fields will be added.
The better approach is to use the *static cell table view*
/ *dynamic cell table view* as the whole, rather then using the table view inside a view.
where you can add any number of cell and modify it in the view. In that case the button will added to a cell and visibility and the click issue will not occur.

Comment: Thanks a lot ...What You said above is correct,for this dynamically I increased the UIView also now the button working perfect..

Answer (score 1):

Well their are certain reasons when button is not working which are as follows:-

1) It may happens if any label, view appears at the top of the button 
2) The action which you have created using storyboard is not connected properly

Comment: I am moving next viewcontroller programmatically ,if any label is appear at the top of button means how can overcome that problem

Comment: over tableview expanded everything was aligned perfectly then how would label ,view appear at the top of the button.